# Why does phaser flash on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm creating a game both for desktop and mobile using phaser. But when I try to test it on mobile it flashes a lot and is barely playable. Links: http://game.r4u.nl/frog/testing/testing/ and http://game.r4u.nl

How to fix this?

Comment: It seems that you might be experiencing issues with webGL compatibility. Apparently, not every webGL capability is going to run smothly on mobile. You have to look resources like here [html5gamedevs](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3980-common-phaser-cocoonjs-issues/#entry40608)

Comment: Have you tried your game on another mobile device? Have you tried your on browser in mobile mode? Maybe it's an issue with the device's browser compatibility

Answer (score 1):

It really depends of your mobile model, navigator, among other things (HTC One M7, Chrome works fine for me). But as other people already said, webGL doesn't work well in some devices. Try disabling WebGL rendering in Phaser and fallback into traditional Canvas rendering modifing the game launcher in your assets/js/main.js file...

```
game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '');
```

...And your game would run at least different. (The speed can be another factors too like physics, but that's another thing...)

Also take note of debug-rendering stuff. In case of the frog, you are rendering an square each frame in a way that makes some issues in some envoriments (that's beacuse it's just for debugging pruposes).